# VS2010 - Linker error with adding static library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, static-libraries, lnk2019

I wanted to create a static library to use in my project like **Boost library** for example.
So I created a **Win32 console application** project and I chose **static library** and I compiled it.
Then, in my project I added the directory containing .h file in *Properties/Configuration Properties/VC++ Directorie/Include Directories* and the directory containing .lib file in *Properties/Configuration Properties/VC++ Directorie/Libraries Directories* like **Boost library**, but I have error "LNK2019 unresolved external symbol".

Why it simply doesn't work like boost library while I make the same process?

Comment: You probably need to add the library to the linker inputs

Comment: Why with boost, I don't need to add it to the linker inputs?

Comment: I have no idea how boost works, so I can't tell you.

Comment: How to create or add a static library without add it to the linker inputs. Because I frequently use library which I include it as describe in my first post (my question). Else when I add it to the linker inputs, it doesn't work : error LNK2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you forgot to write:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "boost.lib")
```

in your code

Comment: No, boost works very good. This is my own library I created which doesn't work.

Comment: just replace "boost.lib" with your own library name

Comment: maybe because of different CRT libraries. try to set /MDd for both application and library
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx

Comment: I was wrong. Actually, #pragma comment(lib, "myLib.lib") works perfectly. I had #pragma comment(lib, "myLib.lib") in my header file and it works with adding the directory containing .h file in Properties/Configuration Properties/VC++ Directorie/Include Directories and the directory containing .lib file in Properties/Configuration Properties/VC++ Directorie/Libraries Directories. Sorry and thx.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the name of the library to use (in additional dependencies in the linker options) *as well* as tell it which directory the additional libraries are in.

You can use `#pragma comment` instead, but it can be more manageable to use the build settings.

Comment: Why with boost, I don't need to add it to the linker inputs?

Comment: Boost is partly header only, so you don't have to link any library to use it. And I am not sure if boost also suuport pragma comment linkage.

Comment: First, boost *is* partly header only - apart from the libraries. Second, anything can use the pragma comment lib, but since was given in another answer I wanted to point out there are other ways of doing this - you can get in a mess if you need different debug and release versions.